# Optimisation postgres windows query

Tags: postgresql

I need some guidance with this query being too slow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
  id,
  views - lead(views)
  OVER (PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY update_date DESC) vdiff
FROM videoupdate;
```

With 10 million+ rows it takes ~30 seconds. I have created a multicolumn index that reduced the original time from 1 minute. I want to see difference between views for each row partitioned by id. Some thoughts I had:

- After table update create TABLE AS with the query and select from it.
- Move old data to backup and shrink table.
- Look up data warehouse?
- Change database schema?

Comment: I'm not sure what that returns because it's undefined. You're using `DISTINCT ON` without and `ORDER BY`? I'm assuming it's `ordered by update _date DESC`

Comment: I figured I didn't need to add ORDER BY when I have it in the window function. It should be ordered by update_date, yes. I believe I tested this. Nonetheless, the query still takes too long. @EvanCarroll

Comment: You could try to remove the `distinct on` and use a `row_number()` over the same window as the lead() function and use that row number to get the distinct ID.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think that will work, because he needs the `lead()` and `WHERE` runs  before the window function. So the distinct on is still the best bet.

Comment: No I mean something like this: https://privatebin.net/?4a099990e0b73a44#E8QlOaIYBmqYqcXSjLS6hoyMscPCHcBdj7wXUvIzqpc=

Comment: Missing: your objective, your version of Postgres, your table definition, the definition of the index you mention, information about the environment. Pretty much everything a performance question needs. [Consider instructions here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Answer (score 0):

Following @a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion again, because he's really smart though super, super-resilient to using the **Post Your Answer** functionality.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(id),
  id,
  views - lead(views) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY update_date DESC) AS vdiff
FROM (
  SELECT id,
    views,
    update_desc,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY update_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM videoupdate
) AS t
WHERE rn <=2
ORDER BY id, update_desc DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try it out as soon as possible. @evancarrol

Comment: @Misa not yet, it's not right.

Comment: @Misa try that. =)